# How can I use regex expression to match database and table name given in textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, regex

I want to match my database and table name just as in mysql query like I want to match 
[Database Name].[dbo].[Table Name] so this means I want to match starting square brackets then any word closing square bracket then .[dob] as it is and then again dot starting square brackets and any word and closing square bracket so far I have tried this /[.*].[/ which matches [anyWord].[ but how can I complete it?

Comment: can you give sample input and output?  Also punctuation helps.

Comment: do you need to match YOUR database and table names, or ANY database names based on the format?

Comment: @markg Any Database and Table names on the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var query = @"SELECT * FROM [Database Name].[dbo].[Table Name]";
 var match = Regex.Match(query, @"\[([^\]]+)\]\.\[dbo\]\.\[([^\]]+)\]").Groups;
 var database = match[1].ToString();
 var table = match[2].ToString();

 //database = "Database Name"
 //table = "Table Name"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

You were close. You need to escape the square brackets.

[Debuggex Sample](https://www.debuggex.com/r/sqLDYEoAII3CTYMA)

```
\[(.+?)\]
```

Comment: thank you for your help. but I want to match "[dbo]" as it is, means that in center you can not give [abcd]

Comment: Oh sure, I overlooked this requirement. Next time I have to read more carefully ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
\[(.+?)\]\.\[(.+?)\]\.\[(.+?)\]
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I want to match [dbo] as it is